# Is it possible to update Ubuntu 14.04 Wubi to 14.10 without having to reinstall?

Tags: 14.04, windows, windows-7, 14.10, wubi

I know that Wubi is buggy, dead, etc. However, I do not have a spare partition space lying around, ready to use on the computer (running Windows 7, using BIOS not UEFI, was bought way before Win8 was announced), I have installed Wubi on that computer in the past, but that was back when 12.04 was current. I was wondering if it was possible to update from Ubuntu 14.04 installed using Wubi to 14.10 without having to go through a reinstall without Wubi?

Comment: yes. and it is also possible for an upgrade to fail. back up your data before you upgrade. If you want to use Ubuntu long term I highly suggest you do a standard install. Also why upgrade to 14.10 when 15.04 is due out soon ?

Comment: bodhi.zazen. I really just want a fully updated Ubuntu OS for now, so I can get developing, however, it's been a pain in the arse to even get the USB I was going to use originally to work, and now I just want to resort to wubi for the ease it used to be back when they were provided option, while still having the newest version

Comment: IMO, wubi is not for long term use . You can try to upgrade if you wish, but, as I said, 15.04 is about to be released, so 14.10 is not the latest. Other options are Virtualbox.